# In Camel multicast, is there a way to exit before all recipients have returned?

Tags: apache-camel, multicast

I need to send a message to several recipients, then continue with the route after a dynamic timeout value (i.e. a value which is different for each exchange) -- regardless of whether one or more of the recipients managed to return something.
I thought I could perform this via a multicast where one of the branches is a timer, but I can't seem to find a way to tell multicast to finish when one branch arrives, ignoring the other branch. It's somewhat similar to aggregate's completionSize perhaps, but the appropriate EIP for my case is multicast, so before I think the ugly solution, I asked ...

Comment: [Multicast](http://camel.apache.org/multicast.html) already has a `timeout` setting, so what am I missing?

Comment: It's not dynamic. You cannot change it based on an expression.

Answer (score 0):

I think,,When Aggregator receive first data , Aggregator send message to next route using producer template .

Comment: Aggregator is a solution, but, to my understanding, it completely changes the flow. I want to send the same message to several recipients (like multicast or recipientList) then wait for a dynamic (exchange based) time and move forward with just those answers which are available, discarding the rest (but not waiting for them). With Aggregator, I need to have each recipient as a separate route.